# Can't click edit on a user's question

Tags: support, edits

Consider:

[image]

I wanted to click edit on a user's question, because I've seen a lot of grammar to be improved and also redundancy and incorrect spelling, but I can't click edit. How and why?

Comment: Well, you obviously were able to click the edit link. But, you probably ran into some trouble after you did. What, exactly, happened?

Comment: You should really provide more information like the link for the post.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267539/stack-overflow-requires-external-js-from-another-domain - if you've blocked some JS, some site features won't work. Do a full refresh and check that you're not blocking stuff

Comment: Now I know that I'm wrong in asking this question, but how do I delete this question? I realized that I'am really wrong about this.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's a good enough question (even if your mis-tagging really hurt you: Avoid crying bug so early, and *read the tag-wiki* for tags you use!). Anyway, this is meta so it really won't hurt you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5447083), you'll see that a [suggested edit was approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5447083) around the time that you ran into this issue. You should be able to edit the post now, but you don't need to because [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25091849/revisions) shows that the suggested edit awaiting approval when you saw the post fixed the grammar (with some help from a reviewer who improved the edit).

Only one suggested edit can be in the [Suggested Edits Review Queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) at once, so you cannot submit more suggested edits until that one has been approved or rejected. Since you have less than 2000 reputation, your edits are suggested edits, so the edit button is disabled while the current edit is pending approval: this is evident from the tooltip that appears when you hover over the disabled button.

On large sites like Stack Overflow, edits are approved/rejected very quickly ([even if they shouldn't be](//meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/edits)), so you should refresh the page or come back after a few minutes and check to see whether the edit was approved and, if so, whether it fixed what you wanted to fix. If it didn't, feel free to suggest another edit with the proposed change.

Once you gain 2000 reputation, your edits will be [applied immediately](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) and will not be sent to a review queue.

Comment: Suggest adding: No fear, there's little delay in approving edits, even for many which should be rejected. Refresh in a minute or two.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @AstroCD! @Deduplicator thanks for adding that information.